# how to tell vb.net to wait untiil done loading? (iframe.dll)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to create a script to navigate to a webpage, wait for the elements to load, and then gather elements from the new page.  As it stands, this script is running straight through when it should be waiting at:

```
Do Until AxWebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
```

afer it processes:

```
htmldoc.getElementsByName("GetCase").item(0).click() 'click the submit button
```

I get the messagebox popup for the second sub immediately, when in reality the page hasnt finished loading yet.  How do I account for this and have the script wait until the page is ready, then make htmldoc = axwebbrowser1.document

```
Private Sub GetCase()

    htmldoc = AxWebBrowser1.Document.frames("top").document 'set the top frame to be searched for

    setval = htmldoc.getElementsByName("caseNum").item(0) 'grab the input name for contracts

    setval.value = TextBox1.Text 'set the textbox value into the web form input
    TextBox1.Clear()

    htmldoc.getElementsByName("GetCase").item(0).click() 'click the submit button


    Do Until AxWebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete 'do events until it is complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop


    If ComboBox1.Text = "MM" Then
        Gather()

    End If

End Sub



Private Sub Gather()
    Do Until AxWebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete 'do events until it is complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    htmldoc = AxWebBrowser1.Document
    MessageBox.Show("got elements")


End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is unlikely to work well.  A click event tends to invoke some Javascript.  Which does not affect the ready state of the browser at all.  In fact, script execution is entirely un-observable, other than the delayed side-effects it may have.  All of this code, minus the DoEvents, belongs in the DocumentCompleted event handler.

Comment: I thought about that, but my page seems to load an intermediary page, and then proceed to finally load my last page, with no referring url available. Thanks for the valuable insight.  I could do something along the lines of on document_complete, check for unique elements to that page, and if they are not nothing, call the sub that way.  Is that the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after click(), before check ReadyState, you need wait for some time, i.e. 2 seconds, to allow browser response to the click event. something like:

```
for i as integer = 0 to 10
    Sleep(200)
    Application.Doevent()
next
```

then check readystate

Comment: Close the form while this loop is running and watch the carnage.